# Delphi 7 Windows Vista/7 Firewall Exception Network Locations

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, delphi-7, windows-firewall

I have this chunk of code which I found and implemented according to http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/networking/windowsfirewall/

```
procedure AddExceptionToFirewall (Caption: String; Executable: String);
var
  FirewallMsg: OleVariant;
  Application: OleVariant;
  CurrentProfile: OleVariant;
begin
  FirewallMsg:= CreateOLEObject ('HNetCfg.FwMgr');
  CurrentProfile:= FirewallMsg.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;
  Application:= CreateOLEObject ('HNetCfg.FwAuthorizedApplication');
  Application.ProcessImageFileName:= Executable;
  Application.Name:= Caption;
  Application.Scope:= FW_SCOPE_ALL;
  Application.IpVersion:= FW_IP_VERSION_ANY;
  Application.Enabled:= True;
  CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications.Add (Application);
end;
```

The thing is, on Windows 7, it adds the exception only as Public and not as Private as you can see circled in **RED** in here

[image]

When set to Public only, my program has problems accessing my host via an FTP connection, thus rendering my program useless.
This problem is particular only for Windows Vista/7; on XP, the current configuration works fine.

Please if you have any clue or helpful pointers, share them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with windows Vista you must use the [INetFwPolicy2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [INetFwRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces to gain access to the new firewall features.

Try this sample which add a new rule in the Public and Private profile.

```
procedure AddExceptionToFirewall(Const Caption, Executable: String);
const
NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN  = 1;
NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2;
NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC  = 4;

NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW    = 1;
var
  fwPolicy2      : OleVariant;
  RulesObject    : OleVariant;
  Profile        : Integer;
  NewRule        : OleVariant;
begin
  Profile             := NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE OR NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
  fwPolicy2           := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RulesObject         := fwPolicy2.Rules;
  NewRule             := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');
  NewRule.Name        := Caption;
  NewRule.Description := Caption;
  NewRule.Applicationname := Executable;
  NewRule.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
  NewRule.Enabled := TRUE;
  NewRule.Profiles := Profile;
  NewRule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
  RulesObject.Add(NewRule);
end;
```

Comment: Wow that works pretty good, it even renders the Fire Wall private and public policies manually irremovable!

Thanks a lot RRUZ!

Comment: what if CreateOleObject returns nil ? btw, is there MSDN page for CreateOleObject with documentation what it can and can not return ?

Comment: @Arioch'The, the `CreateOleObject` function internally uses the [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi method , and all the error codes was trapped using the `OleCheck` method, so if any error occurs a exception is raised.

Comment: Thanks RRUZ, it's ready-to-use code. Does the code need to be run **with administrator permission**?